# PHP Caching - how deal with dynamic menus?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm getting to grips with PHP caching, and I get the idea - cache a whole page to improve performance for subsequent visits etc.

The thing I'm not getting is how you go about this if there's a collapsible fixed menu on the page. So a site has a fixed top menu that can be collapsed and its state remember with a cookie. If the page is cached then it will no doubt ignore the actual state of the collapsed top menu.

Maybe, the top menu should go, but I'm guessing it could be gotten around somehow. PHP decides the status of the top menu on load (detects a cookie) and JS can also change the status of the top menu (and the cookie).

Also, the site is responsive, and user agent detection decides which devices to serve jQuery features to (others get a basic fallback).

Obviously I can't just cache the whole page.

I'm using Symfony2 if that makes a difference.

Comment: The documentation is pretty complete on the subject: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_cache.html

Comment: It may be a good documentation, but I can't see how to do this in the manual. I see how to use ESI for a complete URL, but not for what I want.

Comment: How/Where do you use the cookie state to handle the menu?

Answer (score 1):

You have many options when it comes to caching, and all have their pros and cons:

- ESI: In the comments you mention you know about ESI, and it can be used to only render part of a page. In your case, only rendering the menu (collapsed or not based on the cookie) could be an option

  - Javascript: If you implement the whole collapsing in JS only and always deliver the HTML code with the menu, you could cache the whole page and then have the client render it collapsed or not. You would save yourself some server-side code, make caching easier for both your webserver and the client browser and also would be able to collapse the menu without a reload.
  - ETag: This is the most complicated option, but it certainly has advantages. You could create an ETag with the hash including the state of the cookie. That way, the browser asks if anything has changed with the last ETag, and you generate the ETag based on certain cookie attributes (e.g. the collapsed state). If it changed, the ETags don't match and you return the "new" page. If nothing changed, the cached version is used. You can read about ETags in the symfony documentation.
  - Caching layer: You could of course have a look at various reverse caching proxies. They support various ways of caching, and there might be some which can handle your problem.

Regarding your responsive site: Maybe implementing fallback and stuff with javascript would be the way to go. That way the client would do all the work and your server could server a more static page which can be cached very good.

You have to keep in mind that dynamic pages and caching kind of exclude each other. If you serer different content based on cookie attributes, user agents, maybe ip adresses and the like, you will get problems with caching. The more static your page is (and if you serve a static page and add all dynamics through javascript, the page is static from a webserver point of view), the better caching will work. It's a trade-off, and you most likely won't get everything (high cach hit rate and highly dynamic pages).